# Android encode string as bitmap?

Tags: android, string, bitmap, encode, drawable

Is there a way to encode a string as a bitmap? Or a drawable?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: What do you mean by "encode"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Bitmap, create a Canvas for it, and call `Canvas.drawText`. That should do! (That's what you meant with "encoding" the string, right?)

EDIT: Duh, I realized you're looking for something like a watermark, like DigiMark?